# Client IDs that do not have same age in record

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have table which contain ages of client now I need to write a query that return me only those client IDs which do not have same age in all records for them. And a client may have 3 records in table 5 more\less
Input:

```
create table #tempClient
(
ClientID int,
Age int
)


insert into #tempClient
select 61,30
union all 
select 61,30
union all 
select 61,29
union all 
select 21,40
union all 
select 21,40
union all 
select 32,29
union all 
select 32,30

select * from #tempClient order by clientid

drop table #tempClient
```

Output: should be ClientID 61 and 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not all clear to me what you want, but this query returns those ClientIDs that have more than one age. Is this what you want?

```
SELECT ClientID 
FROM #tempClient 
GROUP BY ClientID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT age) > 1
```

Comment: Its not about number of records its about age i need those client ids that have multiple ages

Comment: That is what the query returns, clients with multiple distinct ages recorded. With your sample data it returns 32 and 61.

Comment: wow @@JPW your query is really tricky. and sorry about my previous comment somehow I missed Group by.